# javax APIs already provided in standard JRE

Tags: java, maven

I have an application that uses `jaxws-api-2.2.8.jar` and `stax-api-1.0-2.jar`.  I see that these APIs are already included in standard JRE so I could mark them as provided in my POMs but I'm not sure which version of each API is included in each version of the JRE.  Of course the problem arises with other API jars too.  I've tried to find an "official" source of info without luck.  Have you more info?

Comment: All `javax` API's needs to be explicitly added for Java 9 and onwards (the temporary workarounds should not be used for long term solutions).

Comment: Thank you @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, I'm using Java 8 so I haven't considered this important issue.  My intention was not to implement a workaround, just to remove unnecessary libraries. However I think that a reference of supported API versions for each JRE would be useful the same.

Comment: In that case, either consider doing the hard work upgrading to Java 11 LTS now or just delay this work until later.